# How can I make a TextView object inherit constraints from a TextView object that turned INVISIBLE?

Tags: android-studio

[image]

Text 4 is aligned to Text 3, which is aligned to Text 2, which is aligned to Text 1. Text 1 is autonomously aligned.

PROBLEM: When the app sets Text 3 to "*INVISIBLE*", Text 4 stays at the same layout position. The only thing that changes is that Text 3 is no longer visible.

**How can I make Text 4 inherit the constraints of Text 3**, which are:

```
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
```

The desired result would therefore be that Text 4 moves to the position of Text 3.

Comment: set visibility of text 3 to `GONE`.

Comment: Thanks. GONE indeed ignores the existence of TEXT 3. But apparently also ignores its constraints. They are not transferred to TEXT 4.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [goneMarginStart](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#GoneMargin). It reads: "When a position constraint target's visibility is View.GONE, you can also indicate a different margin value to be used..."

So, setting the gone-start-margin of `textview4` to `0` and aligning the top of `textview4` with top of `textview3` (instead of bottom) should work.

For `textview4`:

```
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
app:layout_goneMarginStart="0dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"

app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
```